# Inserting large sorted data files into a DB

Tags: database, bulkinsert, bioinformatics, sorting

I have large (~100GB) files containing DNA sequences. They are ordered on the first two columns. For example:

```
chr  position    allele    coverage   otherStuff
1    1000        A         10         ...
1    1001        C          1         ...
2      10        A         10         ...
X    1000        G          3         ...
Y    1000        A         13         ...
```

I'd like to load them into a database, so I can query them more efficiently (currently, I do a full scan to find a certain position, but since it is sorted it should be possible to do it in O(log n)). I've used MySQL's 'load data infile' before, but if I'd then like to create an index on chr and position, it ignores the fact that the data is already sorted and sorts it again.

Is there a way around this? Can I convince MySQL (or any other DB, I'm not bounded by MySQL) that my data is alreay sorted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if it sorts it again, it shouldn't be such a problem because it is already sorted. The best case scenario for mysql sort should be very fast

Answer (score 2):

For those genomic positions you should use a **binning** index as described by Kent *& al.* in http://genome.cshlp.org/content/12/6/996.full

see also http://genomewiki.ucsc.edu/index.php/Bin_indexing_system  and http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/957/the-bin-column-used-by-sam-ucsc